# Trigger php on file updates

Tags: php, apache, webserver, lamp

How could you trigger a PHP file to run every time a (html) file within the web directory (lamp) has been created or updated?

**Details**

Static html pages are pushed onto a web server via a CMS. Every time this happens, I'd like to trigger a php file (that deletes the html pages' cached images folder and rebuilds it).

Comment: That could add significant overhead if many users push HTML files "at the same time". If that's the case, it's better to rebuild cache with a cronjob every N minutes/hours. Also, do you need cached files to be available on real time?

Comment: Cron is not an option. The site has over 60,000 static pages and only a few dozen get touched each day.

Answer (score 0):

If your CMS is the controlling instance that is initiating these file transfers, then perhaps it would be best to implement the cache purging functionality as a plugin / add-in within the CMS itself. If this is not an option, then a cronjob that routinely checks for updates and acts accordingly would be an alternative.

Comment: Ideally, the cms would be the place for it but unfortunately the api is very unstable and breaks with most releases... so I'd like to stay clear of it. Using a cron is also not ideal, I don't want it to check routinely but would rather use an apache mod that monitors.